# What do they mean when they say they require current to CLOSE the ARMATURE?

Tags: power, transformer, electromagnetism

A  laminated  magnetic  circuit  has  two  air  gaps  and  requires    0.08  mWb    in  the  air  gaps  for the armature to close.  Shown in Figure 3.1.  is the shape and thickness of the magnet and the  position of  the  2000  turn  coil.   Neglecting  fringing and  leakage, determine  the  current required in the coil for the armature to close.  The magnetic characteristics of the laminated core material are given below.[image]

Comment: CLOSE = reduce the gap to zero.

Comment: Imagine the piece on the right is free to move...

Comment: Why is there a gap in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece on the left is the coil. The piece on the right is the armature. To start, the gap between the coil and the armature is 1 mm.

If you apply current to the coil, the armature will be attracted to it. Given enough current, the coil will pull hard enough on the armature to move it towards the coil, and it will make contact. The gap will be reduced to zero.

So, "close the armature" means "move the armature enough to close the gap between them."

Comment: I am a newbie electrical guy. My next question would be why keep a space between the armature and the core in the first place. I know it's to regulate the magnetic flux but I can't conceptualize what it  actually means, what was taught was that it does what resistance does to a electrical circuit, is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed piece (left piece). The right side is the armature.

You can see how the force works between two pieces looking for it direction of magnetic field H.

The figures below will help you.

[image]

So, the force of both gaps will be to the left side, closing the gap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mahn